# CardLayout in Applet not showing

Tags: java, swing, applet, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm trying to write an applet that switches between cards using CardLayout, but the app is not showing anything at all and I can't figure out what's wrong. A little help would be much appreciated :)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TEST extends JApplet{


    @Override
    public void init(){

    }

    @Override
    public void start(){

        JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 2, 2));

        JTextField jtfEmail = new JTextField("E-mail", 10);
        main.add(jtfEmail);

        JTextField jtfPassword = new JPasswordField("Password", 10);                
        main.add(jtfPassword);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

        JButton jbtLogin = new JButton("Login");        
        buttons.add(jbtLogin);

        JButton jbtRegister = new JButton("Register");
        buttons.add(jbtRegister);        
        main.add(buttons);

        cards.add(main, "Main");

        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();

        cardLayout.show(cards, "Main");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: `public void start(){`  This is not the correct method to use to add components to an applet.  This method might be called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: You're not adding anything to the applet's contentPane anywhere.

Solution: Do that -- add *something* to the applet's contentPane so that you can see it.

Also, you will want to look for an applet tutorial on Google and have a look at it.